# GA Data Ownership Client / Account Owner

Tags: google-analytics, legal, ownership, contract

I created a website for a client a few years back, I setup GA under my standard, personal account so I have full account ownership.

Now, having not maintained the website in a while, the client would like me to transfer ownership of the GA account to them. Presumably they have found a new designer who would like access the the previous years' analytics.

I have no issue in doing this, however I have a few questions before proceeding;

- am I legally obliged to transfer ownership to the client?
- could I simply delete the GA account data and inform my client that I no longer have access to this data?
- could I simply say 'no', the data is under my account?

Presumably neither of us legally own the data, Google does.

There was nothing in our original contract stating what would happen to the GA data in this situation, or who owns it.

I know I could add the new client as a user to my GA dashboard, but this seems pointless.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually transfer a Google Analytics account, rather than just adding them as user:

1.Click **Admin.**

2.In the *ACCOUNT* column, use the menu to select the account that contains the property you want to move.
*If you have a lot of accounts, use the search box to help you find the right one*.

3.In the PROPERTY column, select the property you want to move.

4.Click **Property Settings,** then click **Move property**.

5.Select the destination account.

6.Choose your permissions settings:

- Keep existing property and view permissions. The current set of user
  permissions is copied along with the property, and the property will
  not inherit permissions from the destination account.
- Replace existing property and view permissions with permissions of
  the    destination account. The property will inherit permissions
  from the destination account.

7.Click **Move.**

8.Confirm data processing, then click **Save.**

More info here: [Move a property - Analytics Help - Google Support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6370521?hl=en)

and here: [How to Move a Property to Another Account in Google Analytics](https://carloseo.com/move-properties-google-analytics/)

With regards the legality of actually having to do that, I don't know. However, its probably better to just be a nice human being about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Max. However I'm more concerned with the legalities rather than how to transfer ownership.

Comment: I suppose its nice to know the legalities of it, but I do wonder for what reason. For example if some one was thinking of charging an admin fee for such a simple change, I might just do it for free. (unless perhaps they had been less than generous in paying invoices before, and still owe! ha)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Max's answer...
If it's the only existing Property within the GA Account, no need to transfer the Property to a different GA Account. You can simply add them as a User to GA, via their own Google Account email address at the GA Account level with all permissions. They can then remove your access.. all done.

Probably best to seek legal advice from a professional as to the legalities of you not giving them access or deleting the data.

As Max said, why not simply be a nice human about it. If the site hasn't been maintained for some time, it's a bit hard to understand why the traffic data for their website, is of any interest/importance to you.

Deleting the GA Account/Property/View(s) doesn't automatically remove it, it goes into the GA trash and is recoverable for up to 35 days. They also have the ability to apply for Admin access to the GA Account via Google